# Como puedo crear una categoría en mi columna y agrupar datos de la columna a esa categoría. PYTHON PANDAS

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

Quiero crear una categoría llamada : **Otros** en la columna **city** y agrupar las ciudades que no son tan relevantes: Por ejemplo : ARMON, ARVERNE, ETC.

Lo he intentado de muchas maneras, pero no lo he logrado.

El nombre de mi dataframe es : wal

**Url del Dataset que estoy utilizando :** 'https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/aiza-48ch.csv'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

### Datos

Ya que has decidido pegar una imagen en lugar de código y para no ponerme a copiar tu ejemplo, decido generar un Pandas Series aleatorio similar al que presentas en la figura, en el que el `index` son nombres de ciudades (en mi caso cadenas al azar) y los valores son enteros de 1 a 5 en mi caso.

Este es el código que lo genera y el aspecto final de los datos (lo pongo más que nada para que sea reproducible y por si alguien quiere usarlo para dar otra solución mejor).

```
import random
import string
import pandas as pd

VOCALES = "aeiou"
CONSONANTES = "".join(set(string.ascii_lowercase) - set(VOCALES))

def genera_palabra(longitud):
    palabra = ""
    for i in range(longitud):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            palabra += random.choice(CONSONANTES)
        else:
            palabra += random.choice(VOCALES)
    return palabra

ciudades = [genera_palabra(random.randint(5,10)).capitalize() for _ in range(20)]
veces = [random.randint(1,5) for _ in range(20)]
df = pd.Series(veces, index=ciudades)
```

---

```
Yopum         1
Kabod         4
Gacocuwuv     4
Zaxaxaf       2
Kidikacebo    5
Zofilemi      5
Moruke        1
Yikitihe      3
Titag         4
Patem         5
Bixojepim     4
Retin         4
Fizadevir     2
Fikid         1
Jafukuhul     4
Nizosebeq     4
Sayewu        4
Solinob       1
Dufuqeke      3
Tiyufe        1
```

### Respuesta

Se me ocurre que se pueden contar cuántas filas tienen sólo un 1 (o sea, tienen un valor menor de 2), y después borrar esas filas y añadir una nueva con el resultado de la cuenta:

```
umbral = 2
otras = df[df<umbral].count()
df = df[df >= umbral]
df.loc["Otras"] = otras
```

Resultado:

```
Kabod         4
Gacocuwuv     4
Zaxaxaf       2
Kidikacebo    5
Zofilemi      5
Yikitihe      3
Titag         4
Patem         5
Bixojepim     4
Retin         4
Fizadevir     2
Jafukuhul     4
Nizosebeq     4
Sayewu        4
Dufuqeke      3
Otras         5
```